# How to get the url of the webpage which is currently opened in my browser?

Tags: python, replit

I am working on replit.com. I have created a repl. I want to get the complete URL of the webpage I am currently on using python. How can I to do so??
Thanks.

[image]

I marked the URL which I want.

Comment: Most probably is that you can't. And in the remote case that you can do it, that script will not work in a normal python environment because it will not be runing inside a browser

Comment: [https://replit.com/talk/ask/How-come-I-cant-see-the-copy-url-option-so-I-can-share-the-user-view-with-my-friends/78086](https://replit.com/talk/ask/How-come-I-cant-see-the-copy-url-option-so-I-can-share-the-user-view-with-my-friends/78086)
However, I believe you can still share the code if you click on the Share button on the right side.